# Nuxt.js says compiled with some errors

Tags: nuxt.js

When running `npm run dev` says server error without exception that's why can't debug what's wrong

[image: when running npm run dev says server error without exception that's why can't debug what's wrong]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run `npm run build` to debug in this situation